# Getting param in controller from GET request in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, param

I have in routes.rb

```
namespace :point do
  resources :points do
    get 'history'
end
```

In the view:

```
= link_to 'History', point_point_history_path(object)
```

Url looks like "/point/points/123456/history"

But in controller i cannot get it:

```
def history

raise params[:id].inspect

end
```

it returns nil.

What have i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route generated is

```
point_point_history GET    /point/points/:point_id/history(.:format)    point/points#history
```

So you want to request `params[:point_id]`, not `params[:id]`